# Weak Linking Framework for Printing

Tags: ios, printing, weak-linking

I have a simple project that uses mail and print routines. For printing, i have a subclass of UIPrintPageRenderer. I'm following Apple's [guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Using/using.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002000-SW3) for using weakly linked classes:

```
- The base SDK for your Xcode project must be iOS 4.2 or newer. The name for this setting in the build settings editor is SDKROOT (Base SDK).
- The deployment target for your project must be iOS 3.1 or newer. The name for this setting is MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET (Mac OS X Deployment Target).
- The compiler for your project must be the LLVM-GCC 4.2 compiler or newer, or the LLVM compiler (Clang) 1.5 or newer. The name for this setting is GCC_VERSION (C/C++ Compiler Version).
- You must ensure that any frameworks not available in your project’s deployment target are weakly linked, rather than required. See “Weak Linking to an Entire Framework” and “Linking Libraries and Frameworks” in Xcode Project Management Guide.
```

**Issue**

I'm still getting error on application startup:

```
2011-07-08 10:47:19.819 MyTestProject[47013:207] *** -[UIWindow setRootViewController:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5a2aac0
2011-07-08 10:47:19.821 MyTestProject[47013:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[UIWindow setRootViewController:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5a2aac0'
2011-07-08 10:47:19.822 MyTestProject[47013:207] Stack: (
    43358288,
    44516140,
    43367003,
    42829430,
    42826226,
    9319,
    1149252,
    1153359,
    1178942,
    1160439,
    1192408,
    47780220,
    42637468,
    42633384,
    1151521,
    1184626,
    9129,
    8997
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

I get this when i try to run my application for iPad 3.2 Simulator. Any idea why?

p.s. Code works for iPad 4.2 and 4.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html) for `UIWindow`, the property `rootViewController` is only available for iOS 4.0 and later (and, hence, so is `setRootViewController`):

> **rootViewController**
>
> The root view controller for the
>   window.
>
> `@property(nonatomic,retain)
>   UIViewController *rootViewController`
>
> *Discussion*
>
> The root view controller provides the
>   content view of the window. Assigning
>   a view controller to this property
>   (either programmatically or using
>   Interface Builder) installs the view
>   controller’s view as the content view
>   of the window. If the window has an
>   existing view hierarchy, the old views
>   are removed before the new ones are
>   installed.
>
> The default value of this property is
>   nil.
>
> *Availability*
>
> Available in iOS 4.0 and later.

This is why your app crashes on iOS 3.2, but not for iOS 4.2 and 4.3.

Comment: Ah! Why didn't i think of that. I need more coffee, that's why. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you will be able to print on iOS lower then 4.2 without any additional services. On iOs 4.2 or higher there are preinstalled drivers for printers (if I'm not mistaken) that supports AirPrint. On lower iOs's these drivers are not installed and couldn't be installed.

This is from: [How to Print a document from iphone below ios version 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735715/how-to-print-a-document-from-iphone-below-ios-version-4-2)