# How to Print a document from iphone below ios version 4.2

Tags: ios, printing

need your help. I am able to print a document from iphone having ios version 4.2 & above but what about ios below 4.2 like 3.2 or some other.
For ios 4.2 there is a class named UIPrintIntractionController which smartly handles printing.
But i wanted to do same for lower versions of ios.
I have searched through net but found only apps that could print on ios 3.2 or other.
Please help me out.
Any kind of help is appreciable.
Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that you will be able to print on iOS lower then 4.2 without any additional services. On iOs 4.2 or higher there are preinstalled drivers for printers (if I'm not mistaken) that supports AirPrint. On lower iOs's these drivers are not installed and couldn't be installed.

Comment: Thanks Nekto even i do think the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to go one level lower and write some Bonjour code. I am pretty sure that Bonjour is compatible with atleast iOS 3.0. But this shall be time consuming and a little painful compared to AirPrint.